# Specifying jQuery on() to a specific class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some templating code that generates new hyperlinks and buttons that have events tied to them. Is it possible to use the on() event binder to distinguish from the different types of buttons based on their class attributes, over catching all buttons and hyperlinks?

The code I am working with is:

```
$("#search-results-form").on("click", "button", function(e) {
  // Do something on Clear
});
```

```
<!-- Generated by template -->
<div id="search-results-form">
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to add - you should be using `type="submit"` & `type="reset"`, and listen for those events instead.

Comment: @DJDavid98: There is no "clear" button type. Did you mean "reset"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any selector, Here example of class selector

```
$("#search-results-form").on("click", "button.clear", function(e) {
  // Do something on Clear
});
```